# iAd integration into iOS app

Tags: ios, iad

Now that I'm almost done with my first app, I'm thinking about how I can make some money off of the time investment that I've put into this project. While it'd be nice to have some additional funds to pay off my college tuition, I'm not trying make this app paid... So I figure iAds is the best way to go. However, rather than tainting the user experience by integrating ads into the main UI, what I propose to do is to add a "Click Ads" menu in the Settings portion of my app. This "Click Ads" view controller will consist of as many `ADBannerView` as possibly can fit on the view. This way, if the end-user decides that my app is worth showing support to, he can spend a few seconds of his day showing his support by mindlessly clicking ads for me. Now the big question is, will Apple allow this?

I've read through (as best as I can...) the iAd contract and I haven't found any part of the document where it explicitly states that I cannot do this. However, there is one section in question here:

> 3 Developer Responsibilities. 
>   (a) Valid Impressions. Developer shall not, and shall not allow or encourage third-
>   parties to run "robots" or
>   "spiders" against its Mobile Properties or use any means to
>   artificially increase the number of impressions or Clickthroughs
>   available. Disallowed artificial enhancements include, but are not
>   limited to, (a) encouraging user Clickthroughs on banners with offers
>   of cash, prizes or anything else of value in exchange for services
>   (collectively, “Inducements”), or (b) application design that
>   encourages or is reasonably likely to lead to accidental or unintended
>   Clickthroughs by the user (“Unintended Clickthroughs”). For purposes
>   of clarification, a "Clickthrough" is generated when a user clicks on
>   an Advertiser's message or triggers any other follow-on action.
>   Developer represents and warrants that there will not be any
>   fraudulent Clickthroughs, Inducements, or Unintended Clickthroughs on
>   their Mobile Properties. The Advertisers and Apple shall not be liable
>   for any advertising fees based on fraudulent Clickthroughs,
>   Inducements, and/or Unintended Clickthroughs. Final judgment on what
>   constitutes a fraudulent Clickthrough, Inducement and/or Unintended
>   Clickthrough shall be in the sole discretion of Apple. Developer will
>   hold Apple harmless against any claims of Advertisers based on any
>   issues with Clickthroughs, Inducements, or Unintended Clickthroughs.

Would my proposed method be considered a "Disallowed artifical enhancement"? I'm not really fluent in legalese...

I could speculate all day, but I would really appreciate the input from all you iOS developers who have had the experience of using iAds in the real-world

Answer (score 0):

I think the key part here is:

> Final judgment on what constitutes a fraudulent Clickthrough,
>   Inducement and/or Unintended Clickthrough shall be in the sole
>   discretion of Apple.

Your app would be rejected.